# Copying only headers in access

Tags: ms-access, copy-paste

I am new to access and I was wondering how i can only copy the headers from access to excel. There is too much data in the access table and I only need the headers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Filter your table so it doesn't show any data (e.g. right-click in a text column and filter for "Equals: qwerqwerqwer". Then you can copy&paste the empty table.</s>

As pointed out by Wayne (thanks!), this doesn't actually work - Access doesn't copy an empty table.

You need to have at least one record, so the best method is to right-click into the **primary key** column of any row, and choose `Equals <the current value>`. This will leave you with one record, now you can Ctrl+A to select all and Ctrl+C to copy.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If I filter a table so no rows are returned, then try several methods to 'COPY', nothing is copied? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: No, you're right. I assumed it would copy the headers, but was lazy and didn't test it. One record is needed. Filtering the table is still a little quicker than creating a query though, if this is an ad-hoc operation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a query for the table that selects all columns, but filters on a unique value for one row. Below is a sample query that will return one row of data with headers. If you dislike the one row, then I think you will be writing some VBA code to get the field names.

```
SELECT tblLog.eDate, tblLog.eTime, tblLog.Form, 
tblLog.User, tblLog.Detail,   tblLog.ID
FROM tblLog
WHERE (((tblLog.ID)=1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly select all the fields one at a time from the Fields collection of a table, write that to an array and export the array to an Excel spreadsheet.

Or, you could create a new query, go into the SQL view and write:

```
SELECT Top 1 *
FROM MyTableName
```

It will give you only the first record of the table.  Copy/Paste as text that to an Excel spreadsheet and delete the first row.  Voila!